# Not getting mocked object returned when trying to mock a map

Tags: java, mockito

I'm having some troubles mocking a map of mocked objects.

I am using Mockito.

Here is my function:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,
    SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Session session = request.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(Session.class);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            boolean testsPassed = isValid(agentMgr.getAgents().values()) && testAgents(agentMgr.getAgents(), session);
            if (testsPassed) {
                writer.write(successOutput);
            } else {
            writer.write(failureOutput);
    }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isValid(Map<String, Agent> agents) {
for (Map.Entry<String, Agent> agentEntry : agents.entrySet()) {
    if (agentEntry != null) {
        Agent agent = agentEntry.getValue();
            boolean isValid = agent.isValid();
            String id = agent.getId();
            // regex match string id
            if (id.matches(regex) || id.equalsIgnoreCase(goldId)) {
                if (agent != null) {
                    if (!agent.isValid()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried to assemble my mock objects like this:

```
when(passAgent1.isValid()).thenReturn(true);
when(passAgent1.getId()).thenReturn("publish");
Map<String, Agent> mockAgents = new HashMap<String, Agent>();
mockAgents.put("publish", passAgent1);
mockAgents.put("i-12345678", passAgent2);
when(agentMgr.getAgents()).thenReturn(mockAgents);
```

When I run, it appears as though the Agent object is returned as a Agent$$EnhancerWithMockitoByGLIB$$738eb07c

The mocked functions of isValid and getId both return null, and thus, my tests fail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you stubbed two methods of `passAgent1`.  Did you also stub any methods of `passAgent2`?  If not, why not?

Comment: Didn't copy and paste it in. Yes I did stub them in the actual app.

Comment: OK, what class is that first snippet of code from?  Presumably not `Agent`?  This would be WAY easier if you could just put ALL your code, rather than the bits you think would be helpful.

Comment: And unrelated to your actual problem, but why don't you just iterate `agents.values()` instead of `agents.entrySet()`?  You don't seem to be using the key at all.

Comment: I put in the calling function. This is a CQ5 Sling Servlet. The agent class is from com.day.cq.replication.Agent provided from com.day.cq.replication.AgentManager, and leveraged by com.day.cq.replication.Replicator; I'm not having luck mocking agents.values() itself, but you're quite right about making it a collection instead. Perhaps if I just made a small helper function, performed the collection from map extraction in that, I could just spy and override that I guess. I'm sure there's a cleaner way than that though.

Comment: What do you mean "mocking `agents.values()`"?  Please don't tell me you made a mock of the `Map` interface!  It's a bit hard to tell what you have and haven't done, until you post all of your code.  But you really don't want to mock `Map` itself - just use a regular map full of mock objects.

Comment: I tried to mock the map after I had originally filled just a normal map, and gotten the null returns on my mocked agents. (The values coming out of the map). The spy method has worked, but it has changed my class in a way I don't particularly like. Thanks for your patience. I'll write a clean class to illustrate my problem in its entirety.

Comment: Don't mock the map.  It's a bad idea to mock the map.  Probably the best thing for you to do is to try using a debugger to sort out what you're doing wrong.  Or (for the third and last time) you could try posting ALL of your code here, not just the bits that you think would be helpful.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the advice on not mocking the map. Had 2 problems. First, I had accidently applied two when statements to the same function handler, and then went down the garden path with the Map<String, Agent> mock. All sorted. Thanks again for your help.